# Python - subprocess - powershell - real time output

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

My program does successfully copy data from an Android smartphone via the Android ADB command to my pc. It however only shows the result of the file transfer, not the progress bar.

I now want to add the progress bar. I need to use PowerShell for that because I noticed that it shows a progress bar in front of the file transfer in [ ] brackets. Is it even possible to print that?

**EDIT:**

I gave up on this idea because nothing I could find worked. I instead made my own progress bar:

1. step: I used "adb shell ls -R -a path" (path is something like sdcard/DCIM; -a is to include hidden files) to get a string that included all files in a folder (and any subfolder). Because transferring files with adb pull also copies all files in your smartphone folder and all subfolders. I then split the string into a list with .split("\n"). It was easy to then only count the files.
2. step: I created a while loop that monitored the target PC folder as long as the file transfer is running. The loop counted the number of files in the folder (and subfolder) and showed the user the percentage of transferred files. You can also show the estimated remaining time left but be wary because a smartphone and a PC have different file compression, so it won´t be the same size.

It worked for my purposes and wasn´t too difficult to implement but there are smarter solutions for sure

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True` here? Anyway, I doubt Powershell will display the graphics if it is not connected to a terminal.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, it is pointless. I didn´t notice a change without shell=True

Comment: It seems you don't know about the `Write-Progress` cmdlet. The information you already have (*"number of to copy files"* is known, *"number of files already copied"* is known, *"percentage done"* is known) is enough to create a progress bar. All you need is to run the adb command in the background and to write a loop that updates the progress.

Comment: @Tomalak oh wow thanks. I really didn´t know about Write-Progress. I will try to implement it. Man, I got so much to learn.

Comment: You can look at [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with `-PassThru` (so you have a way to check whether the `adb` process is still running) `-NoNewWindow`, and the various `-Redirect` parameters (so the `adb` output does not clutter the screen).